# Plot lines wrongfully repacing eachother in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im plotting multiple lines in a subplot, but instead of gaining two seperat line only the last called is displayed. What is more confusing is that the line is still present in the legend.

I have tried setting up the subplots diffrently by specifying in the plot function the desired axis but this hasn't worked.

```
alpha = 0.5

ylndPOS = [33, 33.25, 32.9375, 32.703125,33.27734375, 33.9580078125, 31.968505859375, 33.47637939453125, 29.857284545898438, 29.142963409423828,
 27.10722255706787, 25.080416917800903, 25.310312688350677, 23.982734516263008, 25.237050887197256, 23.677788165397942,
 24.258341124048457, 22.693755843036342, 23.520316882277257, 21.640237661707943, 21.980178246280957, 21.985133684710718,
 21.48885026353304, 21.36663769764978, 20.024978273237334, 17.518733704928,
 21.889050278696, 20.666787709022, 19.7500907817665, 20.062568086324873,
 19.796926064743655, 17.84769454855774, 16.885770911418305,
 14.914328183563729, 14.685746137672798, 13.514309603254599, 13.385732202440948,13.039299151830711,11.779474363873033,10.084605772904775,9.813454329678581,10.860090747258937,11.145068060444203,9.858801045333152,9.644100783999864,9.983075587999899,9.987306690999924,12.240480018249944,12.680360013687459,11.260270010265593,9.695202507699195,12.521401880774397,13.391051410580797,13.543288557935597,13.157466418451698,13.618099813838773,13.71357486037908,14.535181145284309,12.40138585896323,11.051039394222423,0]

xTime = ['T0', 'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4', 'T5', 'T6', 'T7', 'T8', 'T9', 'T10', 'T11', 'T12', 'T13', 'T14', 'T15', 'T16', 'T17', 'T18', 'T19', 'T20', 'T21', 'T22', 'T23', 'T24', 'T25', 'T26', 'T27', 'T28', 'T29', 'T30', 'T31', 'T32', 'T33', 'T34', 'T35', 'T36', 'T37', 'T38', 'T39', 'T40', 'T41', 'T42', 'T43', 'T44', 'T45', 'T46', 'T47', 'T48', 'T49', 'T50', 'T51', 'T52', 'T53', 'T54', 'T55', 'T56', 'T57', 'T58', 'T59','T60']

laxDP = ylndPOS
p = 0
for i in range(1, np.size(laxDP)-1):
    laxDP[i] = laxDP[p]*alpha+(1-alpha)*laxDP[i]
    p = p+1

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(xTime,ylndPOS,'green', label="Natural")
plt.plot(xTime,laxDP,'blue', label="Relaxed")
plt.title('Positiv lyndensitet',fontsize = font)
plt.ylabel('Antal lyn',fontsize = font)
plt.xticks(xTime, xTime, rotation=90, fontsize=6)
plt.legend()
```

I expect to see two lines, but instead i see only the "Relaxed" line.

Comment: Both of your lines are plotted (increase the linewidth of natural to see them).

Your problem is, that the values for the two plots are identical. (Try: `for x,y in zip(laxDP,ylndPOS): print(x-y)`)

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is `laxDP = ylndPOS`.
This results in both lists being the same object, instead of `laxDP` being a copy of `ylndPOS`.

Replace the line with:

`laxDP = ylndPOS[:]` (list splicing creates a new list)

or

`laxDP = ylndPOS.copy()` (more explicit)

[image]